# Count occurrences of something in an array inside a foreach loop

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, count

I have a product CSV file that I have imported into $products

[image: See CSV sample here]

If something occurs more than once with the same name I want to populate the ParentSKU field, otherwise leave it blank.

[image: This is what it should look like]

Excuse the pseudocode but I'm imagining something like this:

```
foreach ($item in $products) {
    if ($item.name.count -gt 1) { 
        $item.ParentSKU = $item.name }
    else { } # do nothing
}
```

$item.name.count isn't correct but I hope my thinking is on the right track?

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: please, don't post _images_ of code/data/errors or other text. why? because the best way to test code is with code & data  - and your picture of data means you force others to type in what you already have as text.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey noted thanks

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Powershell Object lists aren't smart enough to know that there's multiple of any one item, so you're going to have to iterate through (manually or otherwise) to find whether there's multiples here.

Since you're going to be making modifications to any duplicates, it may make sense to loop through and find duplicates manually, but it doesn't really follow the "powershell" philosophy / approach.

If you want to use powershell's built-in & powerful piping features, you might try a solution like this, which would grab all the PSObjects with duplicates using `Where-Object`, then sets the values for all those PSObjects.

```
$products | 
Group-Object -Property Name |
Where-Object -FilterScript {
    $_.Count -gt 1
} |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group |
Foreach-Object { $_.ParentSKU = $_.Name }
```

Since everything is passed by reference, your `$products` object will have the modified values!

Comment: I'll do some reading on that approach, thanks for taking the time!